# Documenting operations in WSO2 governance registry

Tags: wsdl, registry, wso2

I am trying out WSO2 registry. It provides nice way to document service information and meta-data associated with service

However, I can not find a place to document operations supported by each service (over and above what is specified in wsdl). Am I missing something?

Is there a way to customize it?

Thanks,
ap

Answer (score 1):

You can click on the Configure tab on the left side of the page, click on Services, and then added the fields in there.  Here is some code you can insert between the Overview and Contacts tables:

```
<table name="Operations">
    <subheading>
        <heading>Operations</heading><heading>Service Operations</heading>
    </subheading>
    <field type="option-text" maxoccurs="unbounded">
        <name label="Operations">Operations</name>
        <values>
            <value>SOAP</value><value>REST</value><value>Other</value>
        </values>
    </field>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks jeff. 

However, this will limit us to 2 attributes only. whereas typically we want to configure operation name, description, parameter(s), parameter description, exceptions, binding etc.

Is there any other options? I really like the tool but not able to document operations details is a show stopper for us!!

Thanks again.
ap

Comment: All of the metadata is configurable. Think of the configuration as a special HTML type of language.  Therefore you can add any number of attributes wither they are more options in a dropdown or a new section in the Metadata subject.